# error in bash script in github action context

Tags: linux, bash, github, grep, github-actions

I'm experimentig with github actions.
i've a problem with a bash script that work on locale but on with github actions.
the bash script try to determine if the version in all files are the same of the maven project.
there are 2 grep in a pipe that trigger a exit status 1.
i've searched all around (also in the freezer) but i've not found a solution.
exit status 1

i've reported the two files involved but the problem i localized in the middle of the bash script i've set comment where the problem appear.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo " "

PR_VERSION=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | sed -n -e '/^\[.*\]/ !{ /^[0-9]/ { p; q } }')

echo " "
echo "- Master version:       $MASTER_VERSION"
echo "- pull request version: $PR_VERSION"
echo " "

FAIL=0

if [ "$MASTER_VERSION" == "$PR_VERSION" ]
then
    echo "::error::ERROR - The pom.xml file of the pull request have the same version of the master branch"
else
    if [ "$MASTER_VERSION" == "`echo -e "$MASTER_VERSION\n$PR_VERSION" | sort -V | head -n1`" ]
    then
            echo "OK - the version of the pullrequest is greater than the version in the main branch"
        else
            echo "::error::ERROR - The version in the pom.xml of the pull request is less of the version of the master branch"
            FAIL=1
        fi
fi

#the first trigger the exit status
#the second is that i need
grep -rw ./src -e '* @version' | grep -v "* @version $PR_VERSION"
DISCORDING_VERSION=$(grep -rw ./src -e '* @version' | grep -v "* @version $PR_VERSION")
###THIS POINT IS NEVER REACHED

if [ -z "${DISCORDING_VERSION-unset}" ]
then
    echo "OK - The version in the javadoc is valid"
else
    echo "ERROR - the sequent file have a invalid version reported:"
    echo
    grep -rnw ./src -e '* @version' | grep -v "* @version $PR_VERSION"
    echo "::error::ERROR - Some file have wrong version reported"
    FAIL=1
fi

if [ $FAIL == 1 ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

```yaml
name: check pull request version

on:
  pull_request:

jobs: 
  check_version:
    name: check pull request version
    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
  
    steps:
          
      # checkout master
      - name: checkout master branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0
        with:
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          ref: master
          
      #set up java environment
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven

      # get master branch version
      - name: checkout master version
        run: |
          MASTER_VERSION=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | sed -n -e '/^\[.*\]/ !{ /^[0-9]/ { p; q } }')
          echo "master_version=$MASTER_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "master_version=$MASTER_VERSION"
      #Checkout pull request branch
      - name: checkout pull request branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3.1.0
        with:
          repository: ${{ github.repository }}
          ref: ${{ github.ref }}

      - name: get pull request version
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.master_version }}
          echo "${{ env.master_version }}"
          MASTER_VERSION="${{ env.master_version }}"
          source .github/scripts/version_controll.sh
```

Comment: `grep -v '* xxxx'` looks like an invalid regex. Try `grep -v '\* xxxx'` (note the backslash). But perhaps the pattern simply is(n't) found on the server as compared to your local system? Can you verify?

Comment: might need to add `-F` if you're looking for just a string.